# Uninitialized Value on Perl code

Tags: perl, if-statement, match

I have been looking at my code but I can't figure out where is the following error: `uninitialized value $match in string eq perl`

Basically the code connects by TELNET to several device and the closes the connection. It is just to test users and their passwords to see which ones are expired. When it connects gives the success message otherwise gives the failure message.

I do not know why is it giving me that uninitialized value error. This is the code that I am using for my project:

```
$telnet = new Net::Telnet (
    Errmode => "return", 
    Port => $puerto, 
    Input_log => $output_log, 
    Host => $host
);
$conexion = $telnet -> open(Timeout => 5);
if ($conexion == 1) {
print "Se conecto al $host \n\n";
$input =  $telnet -> get(Timeout => 10);
if ($input) {
    if ($input =~ /login name:/){
        $cmd = $telnet -> print($user);
        ($prematch, $match) = $telnet -> waitfor(
                          Timeout => 5, 
                          Match => '/password:/');
        if ($match) {
            $cmd = $telnet -> print($password);
            ($prematch, $match) = $telnet -> waitfor(
                                 Timeout => 5, 
                                 Match => '/Windows/');
            if ($match) {
                $cmd = $telnet -> print("");
                ($prematch, $match) = $telnet -> waitfor(
                                        Timeout => 5, 
                                        Match => '/choose/'); 
                     # Aca se tiene que diseñar el caso de errores de clave
                    //////ERROR LINE//////
                if ($match eq "choose") {   
                    //////ERROR LINE//////
                    $cmd = $telnet -> print("2");
                    ($prematch, $match) = $telnet -> waitfor(
                                                 Timeout => 5, 
                                                 Match => '/Corp/');
                    if ($match) {
                        print "Se autentico satisfactoriamente el usuario y la contrasena\n\n";
                    }
                } else {
                    print "el usuario o contrasena son erroneos, fallo la conexion\n\n";
                    $cerrar = $telnet -> close;
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
$cerrar = $telnet -> close;
}
```

Comment: You should add: `use strict; use warnings` to the top of your code and correct any errors that show up.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing

1. `$telnet->waitfor()` returned an empty list
2. or at most a list with either 1 element
3. or perhaps even an `undef` value for the second element.

You see, "uninitialized" doesn't mean the same thing that it means in other languages. You might have had something in `$match` before you assigned it an undefined value. To Perl, whether or not you ever defined a value for that scalar, or assigned it an undefined value is the same.

That might be where some of the confusion is.

A lot of APIs in Perl return an empty list, in a list context, when they fail. That way their "truth value" is 0, you can do this:

```
unless (( $prematch, $match ) = $telnet->waitfor( Timeout => 5, Match => '/choose/' ))    {
    die 'Failed waiting for Telnet!';
}
```